# R packages doesn't update

Tags: r

I created a new user in my PC. After downloading RStudio, I noticed that some packages where not been updated.

This is the console when updating the packages.

```
install.packages(c("mvtnorm", "tufte"))

There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
        binary source needs_compilation
mvtnorm  1.0-6  1.0-7              TRUE
tufte      0.2    0.3             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/mvtnorm_1.0-6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 233316 bytes (227 KB)
downloaded 227 KB

package ‘mvtnorm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpK2ibnW\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘tufte’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tufte_0.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 243288 bytes (237 KB)
downloaded 237 KB

"B:\Program" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"B:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "B:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\library" C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpK2ibnW/downloaded_packages/tufte_0.3.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tufte’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpK2ibnW\downloaded_packages’
```

It doesn't update the packages.

Comment: does the path `B:\Program Files` exist on your computer?

Comment: I suggest you avoid paths that contain spaces, they have been a problem in the past. (I always install R in `c:/R/R-3.x.y/` and a personal library within `c:/Users/me/R/win-library/...`. I had many problems before changing from `c:/Program Files/.../` to `c:/R/`.)